# How to force cache purge of Twitter Card's bots?

Tags: twitter

Literally I am looking for something like this:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

But for Twitter Cards.

I put something wrong on my pages and I need them to be refreshed asap. But after google I only found this post:

https://dev.twitter.com/cards/troubleshooting

It seems Twitter only offers a weekly update. Is there any manual way to purge the wrongly cached pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I just managed to force it to update mine:

https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

In validating it updates its cache.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. I recently switched from the "summary" card to "summary_large_image" yet the validator still reports that I'm using the former. I'm also getting spurious whitelist warnings for older blog posts.

Comment: It didn't bust the cache for me.

Comment: Worked for me, and THANKS!

Comment: This is a misleading answer - since validator doesn't bust the cache

Comment: It worked for me after validating twice. The first didn't do anything, but the second time busted the cache.

Comment: It should be noted, the validator indeed clears the card cache itself, but not clears the embedded player cache for the link. So, for example, if you share a video on Twitter via cards and you change something in the design of the embedded player it will take effect only on newly shared videos even if you purge the cache via the validator.

Comment: They deprecated the Cards Validator in 2023. What's the solution now?

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, but as Vic mentions in his answer, adding ?foo=true to your URL in the validator forces X to clear its cached version

Answer (score 29):

There's actually a simpler solution than what is proposed by Twitter:

- Go to https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator
- Type in the URL you want to update, BUT with a change. For example, add `?utm_source=Whatever`
- Then just reloaded page with whatever tweet had your Twitter card

When Twitter validator encounters this different URL, it clears its cache and fetches the new version.

Comment: Works for me, thanks! Also looks like there's some client side cache: have to refresh browser page for getting a new metadata while writing a new tweet

Answer (score 19):

Following the steps in [Twitter Card's Troubleshooting Guide](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/troubleshooting#refreshing) actually forced the cache to clear in my case.

> When testing and/or iterating on Cards, it is sometimes helpful to test updates on your timeline. It may be possible to use the following technique to refresh the cache with your most up-to-date changes of your page’s Card.
>
> 1. Add Card metadata to a page
> 2. Tweet URL to that page
> 3. Refresh your browser to view the Card contents on your timeline
> 4. Change Card metadata on the page
> 5. Take the same URL and runs it through bit.ly
> 6. Tweet the new bit.ly URL
> 7. Refresh your browser to view the updates
>
> Additionally, you can create multiple bit.ly URLs to allow for repeat testing.

I generated a bit.ly link to the page, then tweeted it, and then quickly deleted that tweet. It cleared the cache right away for the other tweet.

Comment: If it's just caching that your robots.txt is disallowing everything, all I had to do was 1) change robots.txt 2) tweet a link with twitter meta data 3) refresh twitter and maybe visit the individual tweet url.  Now https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator sees everything correctly. I didn't need to use bit.ly for anything.

Comment: Did try it... Validator shows OK, 15 minutes later still old preview: https://twitter.com/Astralship1/status/895342579801313282

Answer (score 9):

I ran across the same problem.

I needed to update a cached `summary_large_image` and the

**Twitter Card Validator** (https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)

was showing zero interest in wanting to update the previously cached image.

I fixed it by ensuring that every time Twitter fetches the page, the image URI updates to something Twitter has never seen or cached before.

This is as simple as deploying the `uniqid()` function in PHP and using that as the `query` at the end of the image URI.

**e.g.**

```
<?php

echo '
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://example.com/my-twitter-image.png?'.uniqid().'">
';

?>
```

Since the image URI is different every time Twitter goes to fetch it, this forces the cache to update.

Comment: Doesn't work.  Not even a change to the image filename itself will suffice.

Answer (score 6):

There is a very simply way to force a cache invalidation of the Twitter Card bot.

If you are composing a tweet with an URL like https://example.com you only have to append a /# to the URL like so: https://example.com/# and it will immediatly fetch the updated metadata.

Comment: Now https://example.com shows one image and https://example.com/# shows another

Comment: This changes nothing for me.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that helped me clear the cache was adding `?v1` to the end of the image URL:

```
<meta property="twitter:image" content="https://website.com/img/twitter.jpeg?v1" />
```

Comment: This does nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't validated this approach but encountered this error twice and these steps seemed to force the update of the 'summary card':

1. tweet link only (removing incorrect summary card from tweet composer)
2. delete the tweet that shows the link only
3. refresh twitter
4. compose new tweet, pasting your link - should show updated/correct card image, title and subscription.

Comment: It does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Got to http://debug.iframely.com

Copy and past your url then click on the right side button.
Example:
Before was Tweet URL:

https://bdprescription.com/entertainment/details/article/21/Full-Stack-PHP-Laravel-Vuejs-and-Angular-Developer/

Next update URL like this

[https://bdprescription.com/entertainment/details/article/21/Full-Stack-PHP-Laravel-Vuejs-and-Angular-Developer?(add
unique number)](https://bdprescription.com/entertainment/details/article/21/Full-Stack-PHP-Laravel-Vuejs-and-Angular-Developer?1)

Add unique any number or string last position of url, which was not given before. "?(add unique number)"
Then tweet new url

Comment: When I do this for a URL to a YouTube playlist, I get: Bad Request: Requested page error: 400

Answer (score 0):

I have discussed this in detail at [Jekyll: Twitter Card Image Caching](https://djzblogaccname137.z26.web.core.windows.net/web/Jekyll-Twitter-web.html) The method I used is:

- I was building and publishing a blog site built using Jekyll
- Change the name of the post and hence to slightly change the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [David Jones' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76742859/21911900), I made some changes to `<title>`, `og:title`, and `twitter:title`, successfully triggering a force update.

Since the Twitter Card Validator (https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) is no longer available, this is the only way to trigger Twitter to update the Twitter Card.