# I am changing the meta tags but the change is not reflected react js

Tags: reactjs

When my website address was shared on social media, I wanted to show images and titles.

I added helmet plugin to my react js project and got deploy. Everything was running smoothly. Then I changed the tags content I added.

I added it, I got deploy and I shared my site link on Twitter and I saw that it works. The next day I changed the title, description, image url. It has a new version on the site, but when I post the url again on Twitter it still pulls the old information.

How can I solve this problem.
Thank you.

```html
<Helmet>
  <meta property="og:title" content="European Travel Destinations3" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Offering tour packages for individuals or groups.1" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/thumbnail.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/index.htm" />
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
</Helmet>
```

Comment: When you are talking about "old ones", what do you mean?

Comment: But when you just visit your page and open developer tools, does it render meta tags with new information?

Comment: I open developer tools, I see meta tags with new information. @AlexeyNazarov

Comment: What about other social networks? Can you try to post your link in Facebook for example or just send someone message with your link? Possibly this is sort of twitter cashing...

Comment: @AlexeyNazarov same in all

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did a little research, try this steps

1. Visit https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator
2. Enter your url and click on Preview Card. You will see the updated preview image.
3. Now try sharing your url on Twitter again

You can read it [here](https://support.shareaholic.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000263426-How-to-Clear-Link-Preview-Cache-Stored-by-Facebook-Pinterest-LinkedIn-Twitter#twitter)

Comment: Thank you.I didn't know the validator services, when I'm trying now, services can't find meta tags on my site. I will reinstall the plugin.

Comment: Hi again,  I need your help. I installed both react metatags and react helmet plugin. This image is from developer tools. https://i.hizliresim.com/4sw6yU.png, meta tags appear here, but it is not working. This is my site url: https://staging.pollective.io/p/RMILTgTK5

Comment: @thekavak Hi, you can try some ways from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207497/how-to-force-cache-purge-of-twitter-cards-bots seems that method from my answer does not work anymore